# TMDB - Angular page. No consigo mostrar la imagen de la película en el HTML

Tags: angular, binding

Estoy haciendo una página con la API REST de The Movie DB y no consigo que en la página de "detalles" se muestre la imagen, cuando el resto de información si que he conseguido pasarla.

Os detallo el código:

**En detail-component.html tengo:**

```
<div *ngIf="movie$ | async as movie">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{{movie.image}}"  alt="no hay">
    <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class=title>{{movie.title}}</h6>
        <p>Release : <span class="p-1"> {{ movie.release_date | date }}</span></p>
        <p>Language : <span class="p-1"> {{movie.original_language}}</span></p>
        <p>Overview : {{movie.overview}}</p>
        <div class="rating-circle">Rating: {{movie.vote_average}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**En detail component.ts tengo:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/Model/movie';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/Service/data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  movie$ !: Observable<Movie>;
  image!: Movie;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movie$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => this.dataService.getMoviesById(params.id))
    )
  }
}
```

Gracias!!

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar esta pregunta y respuesta sobre cómo trabajar con parámetros URL: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225800/actualizar-contenido-al-cambiar-la-el-parametro-de-la-url-con-routerlink-en-angu

Comment: Creo que lo que se guarda en `this.movie$` no es lo que tú esperas

Comment: A qué te refieres?

Comment: Los observables no se ejecutan a menos que te suscribas a ellos, con lo que ese pipe no está haciendo gran cosa ya que no te suscribes al observable resultante.

Comment: @AnaFernández Si estas usando el endpoint `GET /movie/{movie_id}`, por lo que veo en el esquema la propiedad que tiene la ruta de la imagen parece ser `poster_path` y no `image` como estas usando. slds

Comment: No... Ya he probado con poster_path y con backdrop_path. Vamos, con todo lo que pueda ser bindeado como ima imagen...
Lo que sí que me he dado cuenta es que en consola, backdrop_path (que creo que sería lo correcto a utilizar) me devuelve ""https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/originalnull?api_key=...." Me está devolviendo un "null" donde tendría que mostrar el id.... Se te ocurre alguna solución con respecto a esto último?

Comment: @AnaFernández las propiedades backdrop_path y poster_path deben devolver un string del tipo `/kgfjxysf7afshaslwqj3hs.jpg`. Si te están devolviendo `null`, a lo mejor es que justo para esa película no hay registrada una imagen. Prueba con otro id de película (la 550 tiene ambas) a ver si así si te funciona.