# Evitar la lectura de un dato que aun no ha sido definido en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con The Movie Database y quiero evitar que en la consola me salga un error de tipo "Undefined".

Entiendo que primero debo verificar si el objeto o variable al que estoy tratando de acceder existe o está definido con una verificación if(), pero la verdad que esto no sé como traducirlo a código ni sé donde debo implementarlo.

Os pego el código de "movieDetails.html" para que os hagáis una mejor idea de lo que necesitaría.

Muchas gracias!!

```
<div #moviedetails class="movie-details">

  <section class="header" >
      <app-header [data]="movieDetails"></app-header>
  </section>


  <main id="main">
      <div class="movie-poster-img">
          <div *ngIf="movieDetails.poster_path==null;then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
          <ng-template #thenBlock><img src="assets/images/no-image.png" alt="figure" class="no-image"></ng-template>
          <ng-template #elseBlock><img [attr.src]="highqualityImgUrl+movieDetails.poster_path" alt="{{movieDetails.title}}"></ng-template>
      </div>
  </main>


  <div class="text-center mt-5" *ngIf="movieDetails.logoList!=null">
      <img id="movie-logo" src="{{imgUrl+movieDetails.logoList.file_path}}">
  </div>


  <h1 class="movie-heading mt-5">More About {{movieDetails.title}}</h1>
  <div class="movie-content">
      <table class="details-table">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Original Name</td>
                  <td  class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.original_title}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Release Date</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.release_date | date}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Status</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.status}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Run Time</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.runtime+" min"}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Rating</td>
                  <td  class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value" > {{'( '+movieDetails.vote_average+' / 10 )'}}
                      <ngb-rating [max]="10" [(rate)]="movieDetails.vote_average" [readonly]="true"></ngb-rating>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Original Language</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.original_lan}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tr-overview">
                  <td class="details-name">OverView</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value movie-description">{{movieDetails.overview}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Production</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">
                      <span *ngFor="let prod of movieDetails.production_companies; let i=index;">
                              <span>{{prod.name}}<span *ngIf='movieDetails.production_companies.length!=i+1'> , </span>
                            </span>
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Genres</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">
                      <span *ngFor="let genre of movieDetails.genre;let i=index;">
                          {{genre.name}}
                          <span *ngIf='movieDetails.genre.length != i+1'> , </span>
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si necesitáis el contenido de movieDetails.ts, os lo facilitaría también en cualquier respuesta.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MovieDetails} from 'src/app/core/interface/movie-details';
import myAppConfig from 'src/app/core/config/my-app-config';
import { MoviesService } from 'src/app/services/movies.service';

var movie_id=0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-details',
  templateUrl: './movie-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-details.component.scss']
})
export class MovieDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  imgUrl:string=myAppConfig.tmdb.imgUrl;
  highqualityImgUrl:string=myAppConfig.tmdb.highQualityImgUrl;

  movieDetails:MovieDetails={} as MovieDetails;

  windowScrolled: boolean=false;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router,private movieservice:MoviesService,private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    let id=this.route.snapshot?.params['id'];
    movie_id=id;
    this.movieDetails.crewList=[];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router?.navigateByUrl('/moviedetails/'+movie_id);

    this.getMovieDetails(movie_id);
  }

  getMovieDetails(id:number) {


    let api_url=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+'/movie/'+id+'?'+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
    this.getMovieDetailsData(api_url);

    
    let backdrop_url=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+"/movie/"+movie_id+"/images?"+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
    this.getMovieImages(backdrop_url)
  }


  getWatchprovider(watch_provider: string) {
    this.movieservice.getWatchProviders(watch_provider);

    let watch:any;
    this.movieservice.watchData.subscribe((data)=>{
      watch=data;
      this.movieDetails.watchprovider=watch.results.IN[0]?.link;
    })
  }

  getMovieImages(backdrop_url: string) {
    this.movieservice.getAllImages(backdrop_url);

    let tempimagesData:any;
    this.movieservice.movieallImageData.subscribe((data)=>{
        tempimagesData=data;

        if(tempimagesData.backdrops.length=='0'){
          this.movieDetails.background_image=null;
        }
        else{
          this.movieDetails.backdropList=tempimagesData.backdrops;

          this.movieDetails.background_image=this.highqualityImgUrl+tempimagesData.backdrops[0].file_path;
        }

        //Movie Posters Images
          this.movieDetails.posterList=tempimagesData.posters;

        //Movie Logo Images
        if(tempimagesData.logos.length<0){
          this.movieDetails.logoList.file_path=null;
        }else{

          this.movieDetails.logoList=tempimagesData.logos[0];
        }
    })
  }

  getMovieDetailsData(url: string) {
    this.movieservice.getMovieDetails(url);

    let tempMovieDetails:any;
    this.movieservice.moviedetailsData.subscribe((data)=>{

      tempMovieDetails=data;

      //Default Movie Details
      this.movieDetails.title=tempMovieDetails.title;
      this.movieDetails.backdrop_path=tempMovieDetails.backdrop_path;
      this.movieDetails.backdrop_path=tempMovieDetails.backdrop_path;
      this.movieDetails.id=tempMovieDetails.id;
      this.movieDetails.original_lan=tempMovieDetails.original_language;
      this.movieDetails.original_title=tempMovieDetails.original_title;
      this.movieDetails.overview=tempMovieDetails.overview;
      this.movieDetails.popularity=tempMovieDetails.popularity;
      this.movieDetails.poster_path=tempMovieDetails.poster_path;
      this.movieDetails.production_companies=tempMovieDetails.production_companies;
      this.movieDetails.production_countries=tempMovieDetails.production_countries;
      this.movieDetails.runtime=tempMovieDetails.runtime;
      this.movieDetails.genre=tempMovieDetails.genres;
      this.movieDetails.release_date=tempMovieDetails.release_date;
      this.movieDetails.status=tempMovieDetails.status;
      this.movieDetails.vote_average=tempMovieDetails.vote_average;

      if(tempMovieDetails.homepage==""){
        var watch_provider=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+'/movie/'+movie_id+"/watch/providers?"+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
        this.getWatchprovider(watch_provider);
      }else{
        this.movieDetails.watchprovider=tempMovieDetails.homepage;
      }
    })
  }
}
´´´
```

Comment: Creo que si añades `movieDetails.ts` y también el error de consola que te sale te podremos ayudar mejor. Este tipo de errores suelen aparecer cuando hay una variable de JavaScript (o typescript en tu caso) no definida.

Comment: Hola! gracias por tu respuesta. He pegado movieDetails.ts editando la entrada.

Comment: Quizá esta respuesta te ayude un poco: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225800/actualizar-contenido-al-cambiar-la-el-parametro-de-la-url-con-routerlink-en-angu/225816#225816

Answer (score 0):

Con snapshot solo accederá al parámetro una vez al cargar al componente
Entonces usamos Observables mediante:

```
      id!:number | null;
          constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
            //  ActivatedRoute.paramMap: Observable<ParamMap>
            // al subscribirnos el observer params recibira los datos emitidos por el Observable
            this.route.paramMap.
            subscribe((params:ParamMap)=>{
    // this.id= parseInt(params.get('id')!),de acuerdo al tipo que //recibas
              this.id= +params.get('id')!,
console.log(this.id)
//this.router?.navigateByUrl('/moviedetails/'+this.id);
                (error: any) =>console.log(error)
              })
            
            }
```

Comment: Gracias!! Lo pruebo en breve y te comento :)

Comment: supuestamente se navega desde Movies a MoviesDetail porque this.router?.navigateByUrl('/moviedetails/'+this.id);??